# find django/contrib/admin/templates

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, django-templates

I have trouble to see django/contrib/admin/templates folder. It seems like it is hidden in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ folder, ctrl+h wont help ( appearencely all django files are hidden).
"locate django/contrib/admin/templates" in terminal shows bunch of files, but how can i see those files in GUI? I use Ubuntu 12.10
Thanks in advance

Comment: Not aware of Ubuntu's layout, may I suggest looking at `/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/`

Comment: so does this locate show the full path to those files?

Comment: To solve this issue you could follow this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34532454/5170753

Answer (score 23):

To see where your django installation resides, run this at the command line:

```
python -c "
import sys
sys.path = sys.path[1:]
import django
print(django.__path__)"
```

On my system, this returns

```
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django']
```

Source: [Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/)

Answer (score 3):

You should not mess with your system-specific python setup because it is used as a dependency for other programs (which are use python). For example, a manual update of a package in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ can break a program and also requires root permissions.

Instead, you should create a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.org) and install django in it:

```
# create an isolated python environment
virtualenv ~/your_env

# activate this environment, this means that you don't need to mess with your /usr system anymore
source ~/your_env/bin/activate

# use python's standard package manager to install django in the virtualenv
# does not require special permissions
pip install Django

# it will install in: ~/your_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

virtualenvs are isolated, safe, and work with your regular user permissions.

Comment: thanks jpic, should I remove the old python in /usr/ and reinstall in env?

Comment: You should not touch /usr/, let your OS do that. You can do what you want in a virtualenv !

Comment: Don't mess with the Python in /usr/. The system - all sorts of programs you're running all the time - needs the right Python executable and libraries to be there, as a lot of Ubuntu uses Python. If you're using Django and aren't using virtualenv, you're talking to the wrong people or not reading enough books/blogs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be looking in `site-packages`. Assuming you're using django 1.4 it should be -

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates
```

Comment: dist-packages and site-packages both are empty.

Comment: Are you sure django is installed? sudo apt-get install python-django. However jpic's suggestion is the best way to go if you're ever going to work with more than one django project - here's some friendly virtualenv instructions -http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2009/05/notes-using-pip-and-virtualenv-django/

Answer (score 0):

Should be here: `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates`

Answer (score 0):

Since, everyone is posting my comment's suggestion, might as well post it myself. Try looking at:

`/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/`

Comment: site-packages is empty too

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python3, Django is located at your venv. In my case templates are located at `<project_root>/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/`.