# My Django installs in virtual env are missing admin templates folder

Tags: python, django

When I Install a venv and install Django in it for example "DjangoUpgrade" then I am missing at this path the templates folder

```
:~/.venvs/DjangoUpgrade/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin
```

Just to be clear this is the ls from that folder.

`actions.py   exceptions.py   filters.py   forms.py   helpers.py       __init__.py   models.py   options.py   sites.py   templatetags  tests.pyc  util.pyc       validation.pyc  widgets.py
actions.pyc  exceptions.pyc  filters.pyc  forms.pyc  helpers.pyc  __init__.pyc  models.pyc  options.pyc  sites.pyc  tests.py      util.py    validation.py  views           widgets.pyc`

This happens at Django 1.3 / 1.4 in completely fresh venvs, both when nothing else is installed yet and when everything else is installed fine via pip.

When I copy the admin templates folder from a working colleagues correct install it works then perfectly. What is going wrong here?

[We're upgrading through the versions atm so forgive the older Django version, it's still supported though]

python 2.7.3.
Django 1.4.20
pip 7.0.3

Comment: I just found out they were missing the contrib/admin/static folder as well!

I installed them in an osx > virtualenv and it worked so I copied the folders over. However it's still when I install them in the osx > ubuntu (virtualbox) 12.04 > virtualenv then those two folders are missing! 

Any further help to resolve this would be helpful.

Comment: I have the same issue with Django 1.4. The missing files would end up at `<env>/django` for some reason. If I move all of the files there into `<env>/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django` then everything works as expected. I have no idea why those files get misplaced.

Comment: I was in the middle of upgrading through a lot of versions. So I copied those files as well until the problem is fixed in the later versions. (I think the pip install might be broken for old django versions?)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To solve this issue you should use "--no-binary" while installing django.

```
pip install --no-binary django -r requirements.txt
```

or

```
pip install --no-binary django django==1.4.21
```

Remember to upgrade your PIP installation to have the "--no-binary" option.

You can get further information in this link:
https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/2823