# Django admin /template/ folder missing after fresh install in virtualenv

Tags: python, django, templates, django-admin

I get this error when trying to go to my Django app's admin panel:

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /admin/index.html
>
> Exception
>   Location: /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/redditpk/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py
>   in find_template, line 139
>
> Template-loader postmortem Django tried loading these templates, in
>   this order: Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
>   Using loader django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader:
>   /home/mhb11/folder/project/templates/admin/index.html (File does not
>   exist)
>   /home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bootstrap_pagination/templates/admin/index.html
>   (File does not exist)

I have a new Django installation, haven't moved any files, and settings.py has `django.contrib.admin` added in **INSTALLED_APPS**.

If I go to `/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/` I do NOT find a `/templates/` folder there (which would contained index.html and a bunch of other files).

However, exactly the same project, installed in a different machine DOES HAVE that `/templates/` folder. I uninstalled and reinstalled Django in my virtual environment, but to no avail.

Installed apps in **settings.py** has the following:

`INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    #'django.contrib.sessions',
    'user_sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.comments',
    'myapp',
    'myproject',
    'south',
    'registration',
    'bootstrap_pagination',
    'djcelery',
    'tweepy',
    'django.contrib.humanize',
    'analytical',
    'mathfilters',
    #'request',
    #'debug_toolbar',
    #'analytical',
    #'django_whoshere',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)`

And the full trace of the **error** I get is:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/ Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 140, in get_response
    response = response.render()   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 105, in render
    self.content = self.rendered_content   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in rendered_content
    template = self.resolve_template(self.template_name)   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 58, in resolve_template
    return loader.get_template(template)   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 146, in get_template
    template, origin = find_template(template_name)   File "/home/mhb11/.virtualenvs/projectenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 139, in find_template
    raise TemplateDoesNotExist(name) TemplateDoesNotExist: admin/index.html
```

Have you ever seen anything like it? How do I solve this?

Comment: To solve this issue you could follow this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34532454/5170753

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've seen this before. `/templates/` isn't the only folder you're probably missing. And note that you have a django folder placed here `/yourvirtualenv/django/` that has all the required folders. What will solve the problem for you is copying the files (without over-writing) from `/yourvirtualenv/django/` to `/yourvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/` via the following ubuntu command: `rsync -a -v --ignore-existing src dst`where `src` is `/yourvirtualenv/django/` (i.e. source) and `dst` is `/yourvirtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/` (i.e. destination). Next, just fire up Django admin again and it should work!

I'm not exactly sure why this happens - anecdotally, it's pip misbehaving with legacy Django installations. I'll update this answer if I get new information on it. Good luck!

Comment: It's better to use `pip install --no-binary django django".

Answer (score 13):

I had to install an old `django 1.3` with `pip` and I faced a similar problem. The `templates` folder was missing in the django app.

Thanks to @manu comment on @shahz answer, I fixed the problem by reinstalling with

```
pip install --no-binary django django==1.3.7
```

A recent version of `pip` is required. It may be updated with

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

Comment: Yep, this is a veritable way to solve the problem, I can confirm!

Comment: Thank you so much! Just spent a day debugging this thinking it was my code causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With `pip` version 20.2.4 it is:

```
pip install --no-binary :all: "django==1.3.7"
```